# Why are some left and right angle brackets colored red in VSCode? I would like to remove these features

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some of my angle brackets, left and right, in VSCode, Windows 11, React and Node JS project are red. Dunno why? It just happened. Any fixes?

[image]

Comment: what language mode is active for this editor panel? what colour theme are you using and does a similar behaviour happen for other colour themes?

Comment: Are you using the Babel Javascript extension by any chance?

Comment: I am using the Babel extension. I am using Dark theme. Other themes are similar. Once I removed the Babel extension, it returned. I wonder if it is worth it. Ill see. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returned"? Do you mean the problem went away after disabling the Babel extension?

Comment: Sorry. It went away after I removed that extension.

Answer (score 6):

VS Code engineer here.

This issue is caused by a change in the bracket matching logic of VS Code ([see changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76#_independent-bracket-pairs-for-matching-and-colorization)) in combination with some extensions.

As of now, both brackets configured in `editor.language.brackets` and `editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs` are used for matching. However, only brackets set it `colorizedBracketPairs` are colorized, except unmatched brackets. Before, if `editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs` was set, brackets configured in `editor.language.brackets` had no effect.

Long term, languages contributed by extensions should only configure `brackets` that always match (i.e. `<`...`>` should not be marked as a bracket pair or both brackets should have the same language id).

Short term, you can set `editor.language.brackets` to

```json
"editor.language.brackets": [
   ["(", ")"],
   ["{", "}"],
   ["[", "]"],
],
```

Comment: Was seeing a similar problem in Python code; this fixed it. It was kind of neat looking but didn't make sense (only some left brackets of various sorts were red).

Answer (score 0):

A commit was just merged hopefully fixing this issue, see [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175899/commits/8bcd2bc8bab35d56e7e609e9ebf98097b1c77009).  It looks like it is just removing the angle brackets from html brackets.  It was marked as a recovery candidate so it may be v1.76.1 soon.

---

If on v1.76. you could downgrade and see if the issue is still there.

Seems awfully similar to this issue: [Right caret color becoming red incorrectly](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157322).  (not sure why they said "caret", it is a right angle bracket) That issue was closed as solved but I would expect to quickly see more similar issues.  (e.g., probably related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175797).  A bug in the bracket colorization functionality.

There are a couple of workarounds suggested in that first issue until the issue gets fixed, including disabling this setting:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
```

which just disables all bracket matching or as explained in the recent answer by @HenningDieterichs

```
"editor.language.brackets": [
   ["(", ")"],
   ["{", "}"],
   ["[", "]"],
]
```

Comment: When I set it too false, all my bracket are neutral. I just want to target the < and >. I saw those posts too. I tried the second option, but nothing happened. I am using Dark High Contrast. And it happens with the dark themes.

Comment: Yes, that is as expected.  It is just to stop the odd colorization of one bracket while the issue is being worked on.  It has been reported a number of times on GitHub, see the second issue cited above.  Otherwise you will have to live with the current situation until it is fixed.

Comment: I doubt it would make any difference, but I added a language-specific version of the second suggestion to try.  Are you saying that it only happens in dark themes?