# Reselecting my language mode in VS Code lead to some angle brackets turning red

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I had an update to VS Code requiring reload. When I reloaded the default language changed to JavaScript: Babel. I am using React, after changing it to react I noticed that some of the inequality symbols turned red. It might be a feature not a bug but it looks strange. Could someone help me understand what is going on?

[image: Some Inequality Symbols turning red for JavaScript React]

I noticed that the opening and corresponding closing tags now appear to be designed to each turn red even when the elements are nested. It makes the code appear to have errors but there are no errors and it works as expected. Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: What if you change the file extension to jsx?

Comment: Does it in my .jsx files too. I looked in the changelog for the JavaScript react GitHub and it doesn't say anything unless I am overlooking it. I even changed my language detector to JavaScript Babel and it remains.

Comment: Okay, it was this Babel JavaScript extension that was causing this highlighting. I resolved the issue, thanks.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610880/why-are-some-left-and-right-angle-brackets-colored-red-in-vscode/75611142#75611142.

Comment: There is an update at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610880/why-are-some-left-and-right-angle-brackets-colored-red-in-vscode/75611142?noredirect=1#comment133415757_75611142