# react js code is showing red color highlight even its correct syntax in vs code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3MEj.png)[i am getting red code highlight in vs code even correct syntx and code is also working  .. i try to solve this by changing themes & turn off all extantion but nothing fix .and its very annoying to work with that. please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9adp.png)

i am trying to work with react app in vs code ..but it showing highlighted red color when i use  html tag  with multiple child in return statement .same with  curly braces in return statement

Comment: Same issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610880/why-are-some-left-and-right-angle-brackets-colored-red-in-vscode/75611142?noredirect=1#comment133415757_75611142.  A few questions here and github issues.  If someone were to upvote the answer above, these could be closed as pointing to that.

Comment: There is an update at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610880/why-are-some-left-and-right-angle-brackets-colored-red-in-vscode/75611142?noredirect=1#comment133415757_75611142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import React at the top like this

```
   import React from 'react';
```

I think this solve the problem

if this not solve your problem then I suggest to uninstall vs code download latest version and then install extensions like ESLint,  ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets or try with out any extension and also if you have react install globally in your machine uninstall it and then install react again

Comment: there is no problem in my end all things are working fine in vs code you should re create the project

Comment: I am glade this solve your problem please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i am able to fix it by re-installing vs-code and then disable all extantion , restart then you can enable extantion again

Answer (score 0):

It is cause by Babel es6/es7 extension. When i uninstall it everything went back to normal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUHcR.png)