# js functions turns red inside ejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, ejs

[image: problem description]

Good Afternoon,
I'm Working with EJS very frequently and suddenly today visual studio decide to color my js functions (inside ejs tags) with red colored err's style.
files that work perfectly fine with no "Error's" is now turned red..
I think the problem comes from the latest windows major update
does it make sense?
Thanks for Help !

- the 2 ending tags in the last lines is referring to **valid** if statments from above (removed from picture)

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610880/why-are-some-left-and-right-angle-brackets-colored-red-in-vscode/75611142?noredirect=1#comment133415757_75611142.  Bu that was angle brackets.  You may have to downgrade to v1.75 to get a fix.  And file a github issue.

Comment: thanks ! @Mark , Just downgraded to 1.75V and it worked perfectly fine!